# Problems setting up pc for android development

Tags: android, windows-7-x64

I am running windows 7 64 bit.  I downloaded the [android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (windows installer) and it prompted me to install Java at the start of the installation.  So, I went out and installed the [latest 64 bit java (JDK)](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u23-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer).

After installing Java I re-ran the installer, but it still says *Java SE Development Kit (JDK) not found*.  Is it going to hurt anything to download the zip and copy it to my `C:\` drive and run the SDK manager from there?  Could it be that the android sdk requires the 32 bit jdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run on Windows 7 64-bit as well and downloaded the 32-bit JDK. I've had no problems installing the Android SDK and everything works well. I'd forgo the 64-bit JDK unless you absolutely need it for some reason.

I would examine the answers to [Benefits of 64-bit Java Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200147/benefits-of-64bit-java-platform) to see if the 64-bit version is right for you. My opinion is that you should be fine with the 32-bit version (in fact more than fine if you don't get that error message any more :P).

Comment: I uninstalled the 64 bit jdk and switched to the 32 bit version.  The Android SDK installed fine after that.  So, it appears the Android SDK is in fact not "compatible" with the 64 bit jdk.

Answer (score 1):

During setup of the SDK there is a weird Java setup gotcha. I found great walk through at http://sites.google.com/site/mobiusbay/home/android%E2%80%93day0gettingstarted Short story, if you have the Java SDK installed and the Android SDK claims you do not. Hit the back button and then the Next button.

At the walk through they show a simple application to verify it is running.