# Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

Tags: java, android

Did anybody have similar problem with this, I import android project and I get 
errors like

```
[2011-10-03 17:20:09 - Screen] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2011-10-03 17:21:55 - App] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
[2011-10-03 17:21:59 - App] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

I got errors to delete all @Override above functions. I have Windows 7 x64, jvm7 x64. Does anyone have clue what is wrong ?( I done Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties but didn;t help )

Comment: Did you check Eclipse's compiler compliance setting for the project? [Example](http://docs.elasticpath.com/download/attachments/3178511/eclipse-compiler-options.png?version=2&modificationDate=1162773849000)

Comment: It seems Android SDK doesn't recognize 1.7 as Java7 (then compatible with what it needs). Try setting project compatibility to Java6 :)

Answer (score 445, accepted):

That isn't the problem, Jack. Android SDK isn't x64, but works ok with x64 jvm (and x64 eclipse IDE).

As helios said, you must set project compatibility to Java 5.0 or Java 6.0.

To do that, 2 options:

1. Right-click on your project and select `"Android Tools -> Fix
   Project Properties"` (if this din't work, try second option)
2. Right-click on your project and select `"Properties -> Java
       Compiler"`, check **"Enable project specific settings"** and select
   1.5 or 1.6 from **"Compiler compliance settings"** select box.

Comment: In my case (I'm trying to compile OpenFeint Android sample) disabling "Enable project specific settings" worked instead.

Comment: when i use the 1st option the R.java of project was removed automatically

Comment: Do not use 1st option as it'll set compiler to 1.5 which is not "good enough" in most cases. The best approach is to change Compiler compliance level for whole workspace by going to Tools -> Preferences -> Java Compiler and select 1.6 from dropdown.

Comment: But what if you want Compiler 1.7 and still get this error? how can you fix that?

Comment: Google just released [**Eclipse ADT 22.6 Preview**](http://tools.android.com/recent/eclipseadt226preview)

Also they have launched new [**ADT Bundle with Eclipse Kepler 4.3**](http://tools.android.com/recent/eclipseadtbundleupdated)

You can now have your Android project to compile with JDK 7, can also use features of JDK 7.  
 
Just make sure two things:

 (1) you are running Eclipse on JDK 7
 (2) Your Android project is compile against Android Build Target is API 19.

Answer (score 20):

1. Go to the project folder and right click on it -`> properties ->` check off the read only box and click ok
2. Right-click on your project and select `"Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties"`
3. Right-click on your project and select `"Properties -> Java Compiler"`, check `"Enable project specific settings"` and select 1.5 or 1.6 from "Compiler compliance settings" select box. (try all the levels one by one just in case)
4. Under `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler`, set Compiler compliance level to 1.6 or 1.5.

Hopefully it will settle the problem.

Comment: Probably answered, but in the Windows file system (the folder location  of your project), right click and set 'read-only' checkbox to unchecked. This fixed my problem!

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend using x86 version of jvm. When I first got my new laptop (x64), I wanted to go x64 all the way (jvm, jdk, jre, eclipse, etc..). But once I finished setting everything up I realized that the Android SDK wasn't x64, so I had issues. Go back to x86 jvm and you should be ok.

EDIT: 11/14/13

I've seen some recent activity and figured I would elaborate a little more.

I did not say it would not work with x64, I just recommended using x86.

Here is a good post on the advantages / disadvantages of x64 JDK. [Benefits of 64bit Java platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200147/benefits-of-64bit-java-platform)

Thought process: To what end? Why am I trying to using 64 bit JDK? Just because I have a 64-bit OS? Do I need any of the features of 64-bit JDK? Are there any extra features in the 64-bit JDK?! Why won't this s*** play nice together!? F*** it I'm going 32-bit.

Answer (score 8):

Doing `Project` -> `Clean...` fixed it for me.

My eclipse had stopped working so I cleaned `workspace` directory and after I run eclipse when I import the project I had this problem. Other solutions suggested here didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

For most of the people still receiving the error after fixing project properties, you probably installed Java 7 SDK when setting up your environment, but it is not currently supported for Android development.

As the error message sais, you should have installed Java 5.0 or 6.0, but Java 7 was found.

If you fix project properties without first installing Java 5 or 6, you will see the same error again.

- So first, ensure you have Java SDK 5 or 6 installed, or install it.
- Check your environment variable (JAVA_HOME) is pointing to SDK 5/6.

And then:

- Check that Eclipse is using SDK 5/6 by default (Window => Prefs. => Java => Compiler
- Disable Project Specific Settings (Project Properties => Java Compiler)
- Fix Project Properties

OR

- Leave Eclipse using JDK 7 by default.
- Enable Project Specific Settings (Project Properties => Java Compiler)
- Select Compiler Compliance 1.5 or 1.6 (Project Properties => Java Compiler)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with BMSAndroidDroid and Flo-Scheild-Bobby. I was doing a tutorial called DailyQuote and had used the Cordova library. I then changed my OS from Windows to Ubuntu and tried to import projects into Eclipse, (I'm using Eclipse Juno 64-bit, on `Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit`, Oracle JDK 7. I also installed the Ubuntu 32-bit libs- so no issues with 64 and 32bit), and got the same issue.

As suggested by Flo-Scheild-Bobby, open configure build path and add the jar(s) again that you added before. Then remove the old jar link(s) and thats it.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem employing the two procedures of :

1. In Eclipse->'Project' menu -> 'Java Compiler' -> set 'Compiler compliance level' = 1.6
   check on 'Use default compliance settings'
   Set 'Generated .class compatibility' = 1.6
   Set 'Source compatibilty' = 1.6
2. Then go to 'Windows' menu --> 'Preferences' -->'Java' , expand 'Java' --> 'Compiler' -->Set 'Compiler compliance level' = 1.6

Hint: Source compatibility must be equal to or less than compliance level.

Comment: Don't use SO to promote your website.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that u check for the jar files are properly included in your projects. There are possibility that in absence of jar files, the project will not be compiled

Answer (score 2):

As BMSAndroidDroid said, this problem may be caused by a wrong build path configuration.

If you included some libraries to your build path, then move the libraries, the build path will conserve the wrong references, will not found the libraries during compilation and you will get an error.

To fix it, right click on your project folder > build path > configure build path
Then take a look to the library tab, and remove the old libraries.

Answer (score 2):

In my case a switch from openjdk7 to openjdk6 helped. Afterwards I changed the compliance level to 1.6 and all compiled fine.

Answer (score 1):

i come across this problem cause my debug.keystore is expired, so i deleted the debug.keystore     under .android folder, and the eclipse will regenerate a new debug.keystore, then i fixed th

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me

```
Enable project-specific settings and set the compliance level to 1.6
```

How can you do that?

In your Eclipse `Package Explorer` 3rd click on your project and select `properties`. Properties Window will open. Select `Java Compiler` on the left panel of the window. Now `Enable project specific settings` and set the `Complier compliance level` to `1.6`. Select `Apply` and then `OK`.