# Compiler Compliance Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea)

when i try to build an android project sent by a friend, Eclipse gives me the following error:

> Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

fix project properties has no effect on the error and going to window->preferences->java->compiler and clicking on the compiler compliance drop down box shows only 1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7

I have also tried enabling project specific settings and using compiler compliance level 1.5 or 1.6

is there any way to add compiler compliance 5 or 6 / any other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compliance level 5.0 and 6.0 refer to Java 1.5 and 1.6. After you change the compiler compliance to 1.6, clean the project with `Project -> Clean...` so that it recompiles under Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

- Right-click on your project(Package Explorer) and select "**Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties**" (if this din't work, try second option)
- Right-click on your project and select "**Properties -> Java Compiler**", check "**Enable project specific settings**" and select 1.5 or 1.6 from "**Compiler compliance settings**" select box.

  After this rebuild your project (**Project -> Clean**)