# Android: rebuild now requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Why remove of @Override?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea)

After rebuilding my PC I get this error on importing my projects.

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

I have seen this raised on SO and I can fix my projects by doing the Fix Proj, and then removing all my @OVerrides.

**this question is why do I now require to remove @Overrides? and will this alter my projects in anyway?**

cheers

***Edit to add walkthrough information.***

I import a project, I get the error shown above. I then do the `Android Tools > Fix Project Properties`. This now sets Project>Properties Java Compile to Compiler Compliance Level 1.5

After this I am left with a series of errors within my java files. on this particular project my errors are on

```
@Override 
public void run() {...
```

Error marker to left of error read...

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass 
     method
    - implements java.lang.Runnable.run
```

the error hover in eclipse suggests I remove the @Override to fix this issue, and if I do remove the @Override it does fix the issue and my project now compiles and runs. 
Is this incorrect?

**p.s. I just wrote all that up, changed the Java Compliance level to 1.6 and all the override errors went away! Could someone explain (and I totally appreciate this might be totally off topic) why?**

Comment: i think that you are creating a runnable thread

Comment: I'm not sure if thats the answer i was looking for, In my other project it happens against all my void OnClick's? My questions is rather about Override vs ommiting Override.

Comment: never omit any override.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dont remove any @overide notation.

you must set project compatibility to Java 5.0 or Java 6.0.

To do that, 2 options:

1) right-click on your project and select `"Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties"` (if this din't work, try second option)

2) right-click on your project and select `"Properties -> Java Compiler"`, check **"Enable project specific settings"** and select 1.5 or 1.6 from **"Compiler compliance settings"** select box.

refer this [LINK](http://kyleclegg.com/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0/) for reference

Comment: thanks. I added some more detail, and you will note I fixed my project overrides by setting java compliance to 1.6. Although I'm not sure why. if you have the inclination I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Refer this http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-run-runnable-thread-or-ui-thread.html

Comment: -1 why ? because @ovveride introduced later on java1.5...

Comment: ya but he was having compiler compliance problem not @overide

Comment: @Purplemonkey, it's been a long time so maybe you've found the answer to this by now, but the reason why changing the compliance level to 1.6 fixed your problem is because Java 5 only allows `@Override` to be used on overrides of superclass methods, *not* implementations of interface methods.  Java 6 allows it to be used on interface methods as well, such as the `run()` method in a class that implements `Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

FIRST UPDATE EVERYTHING....

Now right click on your project and select "Android Tools" then "Add Support library" it will update then try the stuff i copied from above....

1) right-click on your project and select "Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties" (if this din't work, try second option)

2) right-click on your project and select "Properties -> Java Compiler", check "Enable project specific settings" and select 1.5 or 1.6 from "Compiler compliance settings" select box.

Big Thanks to Agarwal Shankar for the start...