# Android requires compliance level 5.0 or 6.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea)

I have added this line of code to my android app:

```
ArrayList<hashmap<string, string="">> mylist = new ArrayList<hashmap<string, string="">>();
```

it has worked in other peoples apps but on mine it comes up with a red cross next to is which when I hover over it says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ">>", invalid AssignmentOperator
- Syntax error on token ",", TypeArgument2 expected after this token
- Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

I also have a error displayed on the console:

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

I have tried:

project -> android tools -> fix project properties,

project -> clean,

project -> properties -> java compiler -> compiler compliance level (currently set at 1.5 but have tried 1.6 and 1.7 and no fix)

Please help :(

Comment: I find it impossible to believe it worked anywhere; that line is wrong on multiple levels.

Comment: I'm afraid I would have to disagree with you on that, there are many people using this code, and I actually have a validated project with it in, I just can't get it to work in my current project.

Comment: Unless you have your own classes named `hashmap` and `string` (which is a horrible idea) and your own Java parser or it's not Java 1.5/1.6, no you don't. Put a minimal working project containing that up on github and describe the complete environment in which it lives.

Comment: Finally got it to work! Had to set the compiler to 1.5 and restart my computer for some reason. But working now. Thanks for all input :)

Comment: for beginners: note that the Fix Project Properties is found with a right-click on the project name in Android Tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First ,You Should Read  [Java Collections And Generics](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=java+collections+and+generics&oq=java+collections+and+generics&aq=f&aqi=g2g-K2&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i30l2.826.826.0.1746.1.1.0.0.0.0.186.186.0j1.1.0...0.0.rR0l6ahF2W8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c4df1154fc64158&biw=1280&bih=923)

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

and set Compliance level `1.6`, because 1.7 is not compatable yet. Java 1.5 gives `@Override` anotation error. Because `@Override` introduced in 1.6.

```
project -> properties -> java compiler -> compiler compliance level->Set it at 1.6
```

Comment: `@Override` is in 1.5; `@Override` on *interface* methods is from 1.6.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read up on collections and generics, but setting the java compiler to 1.6 does not fix the problem for me.

Comment: then whats problem did you copied above `mylist` code?