# Issues using soundpool and setOnLoadCompleteListener

Tags: android, soundpool

So I am using soundpool to play a sound at the end of a timer. onCreate I am doing this

```
int mySoundId;
SoundPool soundPool;

// load sound

soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

//Use in whatever method is used to load the sounds
try {
    mySoundId = soundPool.load(am.openFd("alarm.wav"), 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I was getting

> sample 0 not READY

So I figured out I had to use

```
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int mySoundId, int status) {
        loaded = true;
    }
});
```

But my problem is, setOnLoadCompleteListener gives me the following error

> The method setOnLoadCompleteListener(SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener)
>   in the type SoundPool is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   OnLoadCompleteListener(){})

I have tried various [things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea), such as "Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties" and fiddling with "Properties -> Java Compiler" but no joy. My API range is 10 - 16 so it should be ok. Any ideas what its having issues with?

Comment: interesting, someone upvoted this mere seconds after i posted it! couldnt have had time to read it?

Answer (score 3):

Use below code. Maybe your imports are wrong. Anyway this should work

```
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int mySoundId, int status) {
        loaded = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, have had to put this down for a bit, I will make sure I accept your answer when I get back to it if correct, thanks!

Comment: well, it sort of works, now it says - error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
and then I noticed that I simply had 
to import **android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener**...