# Trying to import github project into an Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, github

I've been sitting here for hours, trying to use this github project in my Android project in Eclipse. I've never successfully imported anything from github before. I've read everything I could find and fooled around with every possible option and have exhausted my patience completely.

Could someone please list step by step the procedure for this specific project so I can finally use it in XML  like the author describes:

```
    <com.polites.android.GestureImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    gesture-image:min-scale="0.1"
    gesture-image:max-scale="10.0"
    gesture-image:strict="false"/>
```

The link is https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

I will be eternally grateful.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Have your tried download as zip->extract->local import to eclipse?

Comment: Error parsing XML:unbound prefix.

Comment: it's the local import part I don't get - what exactly do I have to do. I did import and was able to run the example app, but I guess it wasn't imported the right way to use it my app. I tried looking how the example app used it, and doing all other kinds of crap

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the instructions below for importing the project:

1. Install the Git Plugin for Eclipse
2. Right click on Projects Explorer and click on import, Next select 'git'->'projects'->'URI'
3. Enter 'https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview.git'
4. Enter your github's username and password and press 'next'(not finish). Entering ur github details are optional. You can leave them empty also here.
5. Select the branch you want to download
6. Enter the directory in the next screen where the project will be imported. This will be your root directory
7. Press finish to import the project.
8. Then in the next step click on "Use the new project wizard'
9. Choose 'android project from existing code'

   1. In the next screen click on 'browse' in the place where 'root directory' selection option is mentioned , select the place where you imported your project.
   2. Press Finish

The project should be imported as an android project now

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve your problem by adding in your Layout TAG this line for the reference to your package:

```
xmlns:gesture-image="http://schemas.polites.com/android"
```