# Error in using binary literals number. Why should i use old JDK?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, java

I am new programmer in android and java. I want to write a program that use binary literal number, and i see an error, `Binary literal can only be used with source level 1.7 or greater`. When i double clicked on the error in Eclipse, this error removed and another error appear in the problems tab!!! new error is `Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties`. When i Click on the Fix Project Properties old error again appear!! I confused. I searched in the internet and stackoverflow and i found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea) but now i don't know why should i use  old JDK? Can't supported anything with Java7?

Thanks for help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support java 7 and hence you need to be on lower version.  Check under the system requirements here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Sad but you cannot use the feature of java 7 in android and hence the eclipse does not allow so.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.really?!! but how to compile another android program in Eclipse?

Comment: @Sensors You should be able to compile the programs using the java compiler version 5 or 6.

Comment: I know but i can't understand how to compile another program in Eclipse when i have JDK7 in my system?