# When I fix this Android compiler error, I am getting a multi-catch exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multi-catch

I am getting Android compiler error like:

> Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

I am using JDK 1.7. So I changed it to 1.6/1.6.

When I fix it, I get this error:

> Multi-catching exception. You need to change it to 1.7. Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7.

How do I solve this? I want to use multi-catch exceptions...

Comment: Multi casting exception? What is the exact wording of that message?

Comment: Check your environment variables, java_home and path variables are set to java 1.6 or 1.7.

Comment: Thanks for the comment sir but I am using 1.7 with path settings and I am on java work with android using in eclipse,.. so that eclipse cannot open unless you set the path,....

Comment: Alex sir,.. This is the Message sir,.."Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties."
so when I fix it( I changed it to 1.5/1.6) I am getting this error "Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [multi-catch](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html) with `Java 1.6`; you cannot, because it was added in `Java 1.7`.

To change the multi-catch blocks you'll need to change every catch of this form (the multi-catch form) -

```
} catch(ParseException | IOException exception) {
}
```

to this form (e.g. standard catch blocks)

```
} catch (ParseException exception) {
  // do something.
} catch (IOException exception) {
  // do something (else?).
}
```

Comment: hello sir,.. Thank for the Response if I use multi catch with 1.7 I am getting "Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties."
error is there any procedure for this

Comment: [Switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea) your compiler compliance level down to 1.6 (or 1.5), and then change your multi-catch(s) to regular catch block(s).

Comment: hello sir how to change multi casts to regular casts