# What is the fastest way to filter data from ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How can i filter data from ArrayList?
for example,I have one class called "Date Names".
i wrote little from code below for my explanation:

```
    public class DateAndNames {

        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        String name;

        public DateAndNames(int day, int month, int year, String name) {
            super();
            this.day = day;
            this.month = month;
            this.year = year;
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getDay() {
            return day;
        }
...getters and setters...
```

and i populate to database like that:

```
DbHandler hand = new DbHandler(this);
hand.add(new DateAndNames(20, 3, 2008, "Jhon"));
hand.add(new DateAndNames(10, 3, 2008, "Jhon"));
hand.add(new DateAndNames(10, 2, 2004, "Jhon"));
hand.add(new DateAndNames(22, 3, 2008, "Jhon"));
```

and then i get the data to ArrayList like that:

```
ArrayList<DateAndNames> list = new ArrayList<DateAndNames>();
list = hand.getData();
```

and before i passing the list to the BaseAdapter, i want to filter it so what i doing right now is that:

```
//filter by month and year:
public ArrayList<DateAndNames> filterTheList(int month , int year){
    //the data from the database
    list = hand.getData();
    //temp list to store the filtered list
ArrayList<DateAndNames> filteredList = new ArrayList<DateAndNames>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    //check:
    if(list.get(i).getMonth() == month && list.get(i).getYear() == year){

        DateAndNames data = new DateAndNames(
                list.get(i).getDay(), 
                list.get(i).getMonth(), 
                list.get(i).getYear(),
                list.get(i).getName());
        //The data filtered:
        filteredList.add(data);
    }
}
return filteredList;
}
```

now, the big problem is: when i have a very very very big data to run on the for loop like 300 rows to filter, the app running very slow! even if using asyncTask it still working slow!
i'm a little bit new but i would like for good advices

**Edited:** i tried this too..

```
    public ArrayList<DateAndNames> getData(int month ,int year,String name){
        open();
        ArrayList<DateAndNames> list = new ArrayList<DateAndNames>();

            Cursor c = myDb.query(TABLE_DAY, null, "name= ? and month = ? and year = ?", new String[] {name,month+"",year+""}, null, null, null);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
            DateAndNames resultData = new DateAndNames(
                    c.getInt(0), //id
                    c.getString(1),//name
                    c.getInt(2), //month
                    c.getInt(3));//year

            list.add(resultData);
            }
close();
return list;
}
```

But still not working..

Comment: Can you change the database query you use to select the rows? If you say 'select from dates_and_names where month = month && year = year' then the data will be filtered before you bring it into java

Comment: Do you need `filteredList` to contain new `DateAndNames` objects, or is it OK for `filteredList` to contain references to the same objects in `list`?  I don't know what the rest of your program does, so I can't answer that.  But if the lists can share references, get rid of `data` and just say `filteredList.add(list.get(i))`.  However, if `list.size()` is only 300, I can't see how it would take enough time for you to notice.

Comment: @user384842 thank's i would like for example please.

Comment: @ajb i'ts more then "300" it can be even 3000 rows and 28 columns.

Comment: Does it have to be an `ArrayList`?  Could you, for example, use a whole load of nested Guava Multimaps to store this instead?

Comment: I'm edited my question look above. in the getData() method i want to filter the cursor before . how can i do it?

Comment: can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection

Comment: Neither 300 nor 3000 rows nor even 3000 rows x 28 columns is 'very big data'. The loop should be almost instantaneous. Are you sure this is where the time is spent? NB the initialization `list = new ArrayList<DateAndNames>()` is pointless when you reassign it in the very next line.

Comment: @Abdellah i insalled Java™ 8 Support in Eclipse kepler. and i can't use it on my android application `Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.8' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties` you know why?

Comment: @Anna check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea

Comment: @Abdellah yes, i saw that before. it's for java 1.7 problem. i have problem with the java 8

Comment: @Anna if you meant lambda -> http://zserge.com/blog/android-lambda.html

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested which one is fastest either asking the DB to return the filtered list or yourself do it using a loop because you can use multiple threads to looping through the list, for example consider using  `ExecutorService`. Instead of looping from 1 to 3000 rows on a single thread split it in multiple groups each of them having for example 500 rows. Then pass each 500 rows to a different runnable class and run all of them on `ExecutorService`. In this way the time of filtering is divided by the number of cores of the cpu. Another way is setting index on the desired columns and query the DB with your parameters. As far as I know the fastest way you can achieve is one of the above approach, you can experiment and find the best.