# Adding netty-tcnative to Tomcat at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse with the following maven setup

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>PushyNotification</groupId>
  <artifactId>PushyNotification</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relayrides</groupId>
            <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.CR7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.33.Fork15</version>
            <classifier>osx-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.alpn</groupId>
            <artifactId>alpn-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.v20150522</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have added these two jars to the LIB dir under WEB-INF

```
netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork9-osx-x86_64.jar
alpn-api-1.1.2.v20150522.jar
```

I have also tried adding these to the tomcat CLASSPATH within setenv.sh file:

```
   CLASSPATH="/Users/williammcerlane/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/alpn-api/1.1.2.v20150522/alpn-api-1.1.2.v20150522.jar"
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH /Users/williammcerlane/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/4.1.0.CR7/netty-all-4.1.0.CR7.jar"
```

However during runtime my process craps out that it cannot find:

```
 DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader  – Unable to load the library: netty-tcnative-osx-x86_64.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty-tcnative-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path
```

This has me pretty stumped as to what is trying to load the jar and cannot find it.

Full Error:

```
33   [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader  – Unable to load the library: netty-tcnative-osx-x86_64.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty-tcnative-osx-x86_64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:189)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:78)
    at com.relayrides.pushy.apns.ApnsClient.getBaseSslContextBuilder(ApnsClient.java:366)
    at com.relayrides.pushy.apns.ApnsClient.getSslContextWithCertificateAndPrivateKey(ApnsClient.java:358)
    at com.relayrides.pushy.apns.ApnsClient.getSslContextWithP12InputStream(ApnsClient.java:354)
    at com.relayrides.pushy.apns.ApnsClient.getSslContextWithP12File(ApnsClient.java:331)
    at com.relayrides.pushy.apns.ApnsClient.<init>(ApnsClient.java:234)
    at com.relayrides.pushy.apns.ApnsClient.<init>(ApnsClient.java:209)
    at com.joemcerlane.restjersey.Pushy.doNotification(Pushy.java:48)
    at com.joemcerlane.restjersey.Pushy.convertFtoC(Pushy.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: which OS are you using? I think its not about JAR, its about dll or library missing

Comment: I'm running on my local mac so MAC OS

Comment: @yyny OSX El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

First, this thread says to load libapr-1 and OpenSSL first in order to use this jar

[Forked Tomcat Native](http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html)

and second you can try out  java -Djava.library.path=. -jar netty-tcnative-VER.jar

Comment: Tried both even tried building the jar to make sure I had all dependencies the build worked and I referenced my locally built jars.  Same error still persists

Comment: can you try 2nd suggestion in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194395/how-to-make-the-netty-example-works